# How to get list of apps installed using sudo apt-get install?

Tags: apt

I want a list of applications which I have installed only using

```
sudo apt-get install
```

and nothing else. I came across this post:
[How to list all installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

but the answer lists all installed packages (including ones which were pre-installed and weren't installed using

```
sudo apt-get install
```

).

Answer (score 2):

as the `apt-man --help` states

`showmanual - Print the list of manually installed packages`

> apt-mark showmanual

So, it should just give a list of explicitly installed packages without all of the dependencies included due to these packages being installed.

Comment: It outputs packages installed as a result of upgrading the system as well. Is there a command which would only show packages minus the system packages?